# Android TextView inside RelativeLayout not acting properly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

So I have a custom Header view that contains several widgets. My idea is to have a frame layout with ImageView (icon) aligned parent start and ImageButton (menu) aligned parent end. Also, TextView (title) to right of ImageView.. Those should always be visible.

To right of ImageView(icon) there should be a TextView (title) whose text should expand based on visibility of other widgets on the right side of it..

So the order from left to right goes like this: ImageView(icon) - TextView (title) - ImageView (unread messages) - ImageView (battery) - ImageButton (menu)

The problem is, the text from TextView goes behind the widgets on the right side of it, like it's visible on this image:

Here is my xml preview :

[image: Here is my xml preview]

And this is the actual xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="58dp"
android:background="@color/view_controller_header">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIC"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/view_controller_header_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_controller_header_icon_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewKK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/view_controller_header_kk_texSize"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarVC"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/view_controller_header_margin2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frame"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    tools:text="This is the text that is too long .........." />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgSubMenu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imgSubMenu"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBattery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_battery_full" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBattery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="100%" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unreadMessages"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/bat"
    android:background="@color/color_widget_security_back_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="2" />
```

Any ideas, why does this text goes behind those widgets? I want it to resize if batery and unread messages are visible, like it goes into two lines instead of one, or to show ... if it's too long..

Comment: Add one more property to textview android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSubMenu"

Comment: Ah that worked! ..Thank you sir!

Comment: Move `textViewDName` to the bottom of the layout and add `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/unreadMessages"` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot add one more properties text as below :

**android:layout_toLeftOf**

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgSubMenu"
```

As per you requirement you want show text right to left icon and left to right menu icon but you add one relative reference toRight not toLeft so it's overlap on right side menu icon